# conditional comments IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

I have one line of CSS to change on a couple of classes on a Wordpress site to make it backward compatible to IE9 (it is currently on a localhost site in development).

The CSS i need to turn off is just one line and where I'll change the opacity from 0 to 1 so the headings show in older IE versions - the transforms etc won't be recognised so these won't be an issue.

If I use a conditional comment, because it's only one line of CSS - can I use the following:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style> 
span, .animate3, .animate4 {opacity: 1!important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

I can't seem to find any info about using the style tag after a conditional comment.  It would seem easier than setting up a stylesheet for one line of code?

Any help ideas would be awesome

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, the way you set it up is correct and can be implemented in the `<head>` of the document.

As mentioned in the MSDN Compatibility documents [about conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<!--[if expression]> HTML <![endif]-->
```

is the way to write it. Any HTML element *inside* can be written, so `<style>` is valid to use.

```
<!--[if IE 9]><style>body { background-color: red; }</style> <![endif]-->
```

Read more about conditional comments at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) or at [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) (with some better examples).